# Using confirm function of javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i use confirm function of javascript to submit form1 if its true else form2.
if true submit form1 else submit form2

```
<form action="asdasd.php" id="a" name="form1">
</form>
<form action="aasdasdasdad.php" id="b" name="form2">
</form>
```

Comment: More importantly: [*what have you tried?*](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

See sample code below:

```
if (confirm("submit form1?")
   form1.submit();
else
   form2.submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( confirm("your message") ) {
    document.form1.submit();
} else {
    document.form2.submit();
}
```

Comment: i tried that ...but both of them are being submitted to form1